# Why won't dynamic SVG work if not handled via createElementNS

Tags: javascript, svg, namespaces

I was trying to manipulate SVG in plain JS and found that it won't behave as intended if I don't use methods like `createElementNS` and `setAttributeNS`.

```
<svg id="mydsvg" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

The above markup works perfectly. But if you try to add another circle via the following code, you won't see it.

```
var circle = createElement('circle');
circle.setAttribute('cx', 50);
....
document.getElementById('mysvg').appendChild(circle);
```

But if you use `createElementNS` and `setAttributeNS`, it will work as expected.

To be worst, both `createElement` and `createElementNS` create identical DOM text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the specifications say that SVG elements must exist in the SVG namespace and createElement creates elements in the html namepace. How would a parser know otherwise whether you wanted to create an html `<a>` element which works with a src attribute or a SVG `<a>` element for which an `xlink:href attribute is required.

In html where namespaces are not serialized things look the same. In XML where namespaces are serialized they don't.

SVG in html looks like this...

```
<svg id="mydsvg" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

SVG as a standalone document would look like this

```
<svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="mydsvg" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

The circle inherits the namespace of its parent.

Comment: Really complete answer. Thanks. It would be really useful if you can show a small code sample for the last sentence.